# Passing a serialised form and 2D array via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm creating a system for work, and need to pass both HTML form contents and a two dimensional array to PHP via ajax. I'm not sure if I'm going along the right lines with the below, or if this is possible:

```
var myArray = [][];

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'url',
        data : $('#form').serialize() + myArray.serialize();
    }
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: is it possible, just make sure you concatenate the `&` after the other array. it'll also depend on how the second array is structured

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was thinking a simple array of an array, where the second array is simply text (ie. myArray [1][1] === "Hello World"). Would that be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `name` for both the data values which helps you to get the data sent on the another page.And `serialize()` won't work for encoding array values into url format what you need it `join()` function here.

```
var myArray =  [1,2,3,4,5];

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'url', //Enter the correct url.
        data : {
                data1:$('#form').serialize() + myArray.join('&')
               }
```

**Output**

```
FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse1&2&3&4&5 //Just an example
```

And then get the data in the php as

```
$data1 = $_POST['data1'];
```

Comment: Kunal, this is brilliant, thank you so much! That's more straightforward than I was anticipating! Have a good day :)

Comment: Glad to help you:)